# minimal looking chapter dependency wheel

Tags: graphics, diagrams, flow-charts

I want to generate a very simple looking chapter dependency figure, something like the image below. Could someone point me in the right direction of how to do thism or what package generated this oen I found in a book I'm reading:

[image]

Comment: Do you want Latex to determine the dependencies based on references, or are you defining the dependencies manually?

Comment: @James I want to do it manually

Comment: What you are looking for is a "flow chart". For really complicated ones you can use [dia](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Dia). For less-so ones options abound: any of the common graphics producing methods for LaTeX can work: [asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/)  or [TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/simple-flow-chart/) being common choices. You can also use/abuse packages designed to draw commutative diagrams such as [amscd](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amscd?lang=en) or [xypic](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xypic).

Comment: If you are not looking for fancy, you can even just use an `array` environment and make use of the various arrows available in math environments.

Comment: if you give TikZ a try, you will find something similar to your chart in TikZ's manual introducing examples. As far as I remember, it is the one dedicated to commutative diagramms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one more solution, using the powerful `graphdrawing` library in TikZ.  Needs to be compiled with `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{layered}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[vert/.style={minimum layers=0},>=stealth]
\graph[layered layout,orient=0]{
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> {4,5} -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9  -> [vert]   14,
9 -> 10 -> 11 ->[vert]{16,17},
11 -> 12 ->[vert] 15,
12 -> 13,
17 -> 18 -> 19};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: The high degree of automatism is amazing. But typographically I like Marijn's solution best

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen All of the formatting tweaks in Marijn's  answer can be applied to this solution too. I just wanted to show the basic idea.

Answer (score 6):

As suggested by the comments, you can do this with the `tikz` drawing package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
\node (1) {1};
\node (2) [right of=1] {2};
\node (4) [above right of=2] {4};
\node (5) [below right of=2] {5};
\node (6) [below right of=4] {6};
\node (7) [right of=6] {7};
\node (16) [above of=7] {16};
\node (17) [below of=7] {17};

\draw[->,thick,>=stealth] (1) -- (2);
\draw[->,thick,>=stealth] (2) -- (4);
\draw[->,thick,>=stealth] (2) -- (5);
\draw[->,thick,>=stealth] (4) -- (6);
\draw[->,thick,>=stealth] (5) -- (6);
\draw[->,thick,>=stealth] (6) -- (7);
\draw[->,thick,>=stealth] (7) -- (16);
\draw[->,thick,>=stealth] (7) -- (17);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: diagram]

Note: please avoid asking questions at the start of your writing process, instead do some searching on the internet and try to adapt the examples you find. If you get stuck, ask a question here.

Answer (score 3):

Why no `tikz-cd` answers?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{
arrow style=tikz,
arrows={thick},
diagrams={>=stealth}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[sep=1em]
 & & 4 \arrow[dr] & & && 14 && 16 & 15 &   \\
1 \arrow[r] & 2 \arrow[ur]\arrow[dr] & & 6 \arrow[r]& 7\arrow[r] & 8\arrow[r] & 9\arrow[r]\arrow[u] & 10\arrow[r] & 11\arrow[r]\arrow[u]\arrow[d] & 12\arrow[r]\arrow[u] & 13\\
 && 5 \arrow[ur] & &  &&&& 17\arrow[r] & 18\arrow[r] & 19
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Easy with the `psmatrix` environment of `pst-node`:

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\psset{arrowinset=0.15, arrows=->, nodesep=2pt}
\[ 
\begin{psmatrix}[shortput=nab, colsep=0.8cm, rowsep=0.5cm]
%%% nodes
     & & & 4 & & & &14 & & 16 & 15 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
     & & & 5 & & & & & & 17 & 18 & 19 \\
%%% arrows
    \ncline{2,1}{2,2}\ncline{2,2}{2,3}
    \ncline{2,3}{1,4}\ncline{2,3}{3,4}\ncline{1,4}{2,5}\ncline{3,4}{2,5}
    \ncline{2,8}{1,8}\ncline{2,10}{1,10}\ncline{2,10}{3,10}
    \ncline{2,11}{1,11}
    \ncline{3,10}{3,11}\ncline{3,11}{3,12}
    \ncline{2,5}{2,6}\ncline{2,6}{2,7}\ncline{2,7}{2,8}\ncline{2,8}{2,9}\ncline{2,9}{2,10}\ncline{2,10}{2,11} \ncline{2,11}{2,12}
\end{psmatrix} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]